# AH01630: client denied by server configuration- static files in django

Tags: apache2, django

My website is working but it is not displaying static files present in my project folder. I am getting this error `AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/ubuntu/project/static/js/homepage.js, referer: http://test.com/home/`

Here is the configuration for static in my .conf file:

```
Alias /static /home/ubuntu/project/static
<Directory /home/ubuntu/project/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I have followed answers online and added `Require all granted` but still no luck.

My other sites are up and running using same configuration. But this one is causing the error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. If anyone else facing it may try this solution.

I was serving the site in my `/home/ubuntu`. I use this for my other websites and they work fine. But in this case I was getting the error. So I moved my site to `/var/www/html` and now its working.